# RTK Query: How can I get trigger from useLazyQuery conditionally?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query, destructuring

How can I get trigger from useLazyQuery conditionally?
`const [trigger] = props.useLazySearchQuery();`
My goal is to get trigger only if **useLazySearchQuery** is received in props.

Of cource I can do   `const [trigger] = props.useLazySearchQuery && props.useLazySearchQuery();`
But if prop will be undefined it will  cause error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
const trigger = props.useLazySearchQuery ? props.useLazySearchQuery()[0] : null;
```

Then

```
trigger &&
      trigger({ value })
        .unwrap()
```